# Writing Server Addresses of Incoming Connections To File

Tags: linux, networking, computer-science

So I am currently working on a destination based routing setup, and I'm really new to the world of Linux. I'm mainly trying to get this to work for video, so what I want to do is route any traffic that I specify through my vpn, and keep the rest of the traffic local. I tried to do this with BBC iPlayer, and I ended up reaching a roadblock because nslookup did not yield the server addresses for Akamai, BBC's CDN. I used tcptrack to find all the incoming connections onto my machine, and I sorted it by connection rate, and the top few would end up being the akamai servers. Well, once I figured this out, I am currently trying to automate the process, and I cannot get tcptrack to write to an output file. Does anyone know of a way to get tcptrack to write to a text file or know of a program that would be better suited to my purpose? What I currently do is use the route command and route the server address, both the one that tcptrack gets me and the nslookup address, through to my vpn using the syntax route add (server address) dev tun0. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand the context correctly but if you want to direct specific traffic say based on client IP or domain name then this is possible using Akamai.

Comment: I want a way to see the server address of all connections coming into the computer, preferably sorted by data transfer rate, Akamai's servers were not given via an nslookup to the BBC iPlayer, but using tcptrack worked. I need a way to automate this process by writing the connections that are visible on tcptrack to a file, or I need a different program.